# How to show certain content disabled by `display:none;` after a certain browser resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to show certain content disabled by `display:none;` after a certain browser resolution

show full content in mobile view & show partial content in desktop view

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darshkotecha/eg3wcu6t/)

As in the jsfiddle i only want to show text blocks & hide the rest of click me blocks in a bootstrap grid

Comment: It's not so clear...maybe are you talking about css [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) ?

Comment: Have a look at css @media rules. They allow you to specify css rules for screen sizes among other things.

Comment: Is there any other alternate to @ media rules since the element receives display: none using inline style sheets & id, class are held by another jquery function

Answer (score 0):

use CSS media query 
go to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
for mobile ,desktop and more